# Inventory Source Selection For Quotes

Tags: magento2.4, inventory, multi-source-inventory

We need inventory source selection at the time of ordering, not at the time of shipment and already solved reservations with a custom reservation mechanism that reserves stock on source level.

Now I'm refering to the documentation to [create a custom source selection algorithm](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/inventory/source-selection-algorithms.html).

Adding a new source selection algorithm works, but I'm curious about this paragraph:

> ### Create a InventoryRequest factory for quotes (optional)
>
> Magento provides the InventoryRequestFromOrderFactory, which determines the
> sources to use to fulfill the order at the time a shipment is created.
>
> ```
> class InventoryRequestFromOrderFactory
> {
>       /**
>      * @param OrderInterface $order
>      * @return InventoryRequestInterface
>      */
>     public function create(OrderInterface $order) : InventoryRequestInterface
>     {
>         [...]
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> To add an SSA at the time of checkout, introduce your own factory that
> produces an InventoryRequestInterface based on a Quote object,
> outlined as follows:
>
> ```
> class InventoryRequestFactory
> {
>     /**
>      * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote
>      * @return InventoryRequestInterface
>      */
>     public function create(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote) : InventoryRequestInterface
>     {
>         // TODO
>     }
> }
> ```

There's no more information where that custom InventoryRequestFactory would be configured or called. Is this really possible, and if so, how?

From reading the code I had the impression that we needed a workaround with a source selection algorithm that would select sources based on our custom reservations. But if it were possible to move the source selection to a different point in the order process, that would help a lot (would like to get rid of the user interface anyways and always pick sources based on the algorithm)